# can lxml/requests select dropdown options then parse resulting ajax?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

I have a site I'm trying to test and although I can get a list of options in a dropdown I am not sure how select it?  There is no submit button so if I select it then it will load an ajax table below.

I'm just not sure if lxml/requests can do this or how it could be done? I would appreciate it if anyone could confirm or knows the function that could do it ?

edit: My site is internal and not accessible but here is a sample site: https://www.tsx.com/listings/listing-with-us/listed-company-directory  Notice if you select the box beside search it will pull out ajax results(A,B,C,etc..)

Comment: Depends on a particular use case I guess, could you provide a link to the page where you have to select a value in a dropdown? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @alecxe I just edited the question to include a link, it's not the exact one but is a perfect example.

Comment: Thank you. This sample is an easy one, every time you select an option in the dropdown there is an AJAX request sent to the `https://www.tsx.com/json/company-directory/search/tsx/<letter>` URL. In your code, you would not be operating on the `select-option` or `form` level, you would just issue the request to the `https://www.tsx.com/json/company-directory/search/tsx/<letter>` url with a desired letter. You don't have a real browser and, hence, operating on the "do this request", "parse html", "do another request" level..

Comment: @alecxe omg thank you Alex that is cool but for my internal site example I'm not sure how to get that call.  How do I get the call it's making? Is there a name for it or a tool I could use?

Comment: Sure, open browser developer tools, network tab. Do the dropdown selection and see what request(s) is/are being sent to the server. Then, your task would be to simulate the same request(s) via requests.

Comment: @alecxe that's so cool. I just tested and it worked! Thanks a million! If you want to put this as an answer I'm happy to mark it as answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `lxml`+`requests` setup, you operate on a different level, a lower level. There are no dropdowns for `requests`, *it is not a browser*.

The general approach to your problem is to:

- open Browser Developer Tools in your browser of choice, Network tab
- select an option in the dropdown
- observe the request(s) sent to the server in the Network tab
- simulate this/these requests in your Python code

---

There is one more "trick" that you can use to ease the developer tools to requests transition:

- right click on the request in the list of requests in Network tab
- click "Copy as cURL"
- go to http://curl.trillworks.com/ webpage and convert the cURL command to the Python+Requests code