# Handle JavaScript events in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, event-handling, dom-events

How can I handle DOM JavaScript events (such a click) with Python?
Is there a library to do such things? I've used *selenium* and _splinter to store data from browser, but I'd like to not use a browser graphically.

Are there any ways to not use a browser automatism graphically with *selenium* or *splinter*?

## Answer

I used a Xvfb *(X Virtual Framebuffer)* to run a browser virtually. Thanks to all

Comment: Try using selenium with phantomjs.

Comment: "but I'd like to not use a browser" - then what's going to be running the Javascript?

Comment: @user2357112 maybe in a virtual browser or with BeautifulSoup

Comment: BeautifulSoup is a parser. It doesn't run Javascript.

Comment: @user2357112 ok, I'm going to use PhantomJS with selenium, thank you

Comment: There actually is a way to do it with requests and bs4 but it involves a bit of tinkering.

Comment: I found it: I'll use a Xvfb to create a virtual browser

Comment: FYI, PhantomJS is still a browser, it's just a *headless* browser.

Comment: Consider this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38081914/7073884

Comment: @LukaszSalitra I tried to simulate the requests, but I had no success

Comment: @FedericoLolli You should be able to do it, once you closely follow Alecxe's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Brython (Browser Python) is an implementation of Python 3 running in the browser.

https://www.brython.info/static_doc/en/intro.html