# Python requests fails to log in

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

I appreciate the things you're doing here. Usually I am able to figure out my issues with the help of Stackoverflow, but this time I'm stuck. Hopefully you can help me!

The question is fairly simple: how to login on [this webpage](https://en-gb.sports.napoleongames.be/) using **Python's requests**?

*My steps:*

1. Get the login url
2. Provide the login details. According to the HTML, I need to provide an 'email' and a 'password'.
3. Create a session and use post to login
4. Check HTML if login was successful

Unfortunately, the easy approach does not seem to work in this case. For example, the output of `details` is:

```
<script>
    dataLayer = [{
        'environment': 'production',
        'loggedIn': '0',
        'userCode': '',
        'rank': '',
        'totalBalance': '0',
        'overAgeCasino': '0'
    }];
</script>
```

Obviously, `'0'` of `'loggedIn'` should change to `'1'` if the login was successful.

In an example I found that you might have to add a 'csrftoken' and that this can be found as a 'hidden' type in the HTML. However, the name in the type='hidden' part seems to have nothing to do with this and also has no value ([link to screenshot of HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8HtG.png)). 
Somewhere else I read that a CSFR token is also stored in the CookieJar, but it is not there:

```
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie PHPSESSID=5dib6cf6kpvf29dsn725ljcec7 for .napoleongames.be/>, <Cookie locale=en_GB for .napoleongames.be/>, <Cookie user=false for .napoleongames.be/>]>
```

I find it hard to believe that logging in is not possible, but I've ran out of ideas. If someone knows how to do it with urllib(2), it is also useful. I'd rather not use Selenium as I haven't been able to run it smoothly.

*Code:*

```
 import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from datetime import date

date_str = str(date.today())
login_url = 'https://en-gb.sports.napoleongames.be/user/login'
protected_url = 'proctected_url'

payload = {'email': 'address@example.com',
           'password': '*********'}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.get(login_url)
    login_page = session.post(login_url,
                          data=payload)

    html_body = BeautifulSoup(login_page.content, 'html.parser').find(
        name='body', attrs={'id': 'user_login'})
    details = html_body.findAll('script')[0]
    page = session.get(protected_url)
```

*Headers:*

```
{'Date': 'Wed, 06 Sep 2017 23:45:52 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache', 'Expires': 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-Cache-Page': 'MISS', 'Set-Cookie': 'locale=en_GB; Expires=Mon, 05-Mar-2018 23:45:52 GMT; Domain=.napoleongames.be; Path=/, user=false; expires=Mon, 05-Mar-2018 23:45:52 GMT; Max-Age=15552000; path=/; domain=.napoleongames.be, loyalty=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=.napoleongames.be', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=15768000', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Content-Length': '10840', 'Connection': 'close', 'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
```

Comment: Unfortunately a number of modern website frameworks rely extensively on javascript, which of course requests cannot process. If your work requires you to regularly scrape modern webpages, I strongly recommend you get used to selenium, it's excellent and solves this kind of issue easily.

Comment: @DanielleM. There is ways around javascript with requests. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38081914/7073884)

Comment: @DanielleM. No, it was just for fun. I need to figure out the errors that occur when I use Selenium. First I got a path issue for which the solution was to downgrade, but then something went wrong with the geckodriver and then the recommended solution was to upgrade, so therefore I have focussed on requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When submitting a form, you should take in consideration other fields inside the form tags not just the fields you need to fill up. In this case, when you look inside the page source, there is one more field that is being populated upon login.

You can try adding that in your payload:

```
payload = {'email': 'address@example.com',
           'password': '*********'
           'buttons_app_service_user_login[buttonClicked]': 'buttons_app_service_user_login-save'}
```

Let me know if that worked or if you encounter other issues.

Comment: Successful, many thanks! So the key was to use the 'id' instead of the 'value' (which was empty)

Comment: Yes the value is empty on initial load, when you try to submit the login form with empty username and password, you'll see the value being populated.